# Enumerable.Last() Throws InvalidOperationException "Sequence contains no matching element"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In a pre-sorted `List<int>` I am about to find the  last element that satisfies the condition such as `int lastScore = list.Last(x => x < 100)`. If there is no element(s) in the list that satisfies this condition, an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown with the error message: `Sequence contains no matching element`. This happens with `list.First(...)` too.

I even tried to make `lastScore` nullable to no avail.

Is catching the exception and manually assigning `lastScore` to `null` the only way out?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Having said this, I am confused by your question.  `List<int>` cannot be `list`'s type because `int` does not have a property `Score` of course.  Please clarify.

Comment: Really sorry! I meant to write `list.Last(x => x < 100)`. Thanks for pointing it. I have edited the question too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault` or `LastOrDefault` to get `null` if there is no match, assuming you are working with reference types. These methods will return the [default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx) for value types.

Comment: In this case (`IEnumerable<int>`) it will return 0, not null. This is actually problematic if 0 is a valid value. One solution is to first transform the sequence to `IEnumerable<int?>`, although I would probably just deal with the Exception in this case.

Comment: True. What would, then, be the solution?

Comment: Just found that `FirstOrDetault` and `LastOrDefault` return default values (such as 0 for `int`s) for value types. For `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a reference type, they return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably *just catch the Exception* at the closest-point of use.

This is because `LastOrDefault/FirstOrDefault` over an `IEnumerable<int>` will return 0 (the default for an `int`), which *may* be a "valid" value - this depends on the actual context and defined rules. While converting the sequence to an `IEnumerable<int?>` would allow the previous methods to return `null`, that seems like more work than it is worth.

If needing to use `lastScore` on a continued use, consider:

```
int? lastScore;  /* Using a Nullable<int> to be able to detect "not found" */
try {
   lastScore = list.Last(x => x < 100);  /* int -> int? OK */
} catch (InvalidOperationException) {
   lastScore = null; /* If 0 see LastOrDefault as suggested;
                        otherwise react appropriately with a sentinel/flag/etc */
}
if (lastScore.HasValue) {
   /* Found value meeting conditions */
}
```

Or if able to discard the case when it isn't found, consider:

```
try {
   var lastScore = list.Last(x => x < 100);
   /* Do something small/immediate that won't throw
      an InvalidOperationException, or wrap it in it's own catch */
   return lastScore * bonus;
} catch (InvalidOperationException) {
   /* Do something else entirely, lastScore is never available */
   return -1;
}
```